# How to make Classes generated in build Serializable and Parcelable?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to send List containing objects from Classes created during build.
and these classes are generated each time program builds.

so can't make these classes implement Serializable or Parcelable
[image]

How do i overcome this problem...!
saving json in preferences and then loading it in other class is not working as well as there is huge data.